# What are the different levels of Facebook integration?

Tags: facebook

I am kind of confused about the many different types of integration facebook offers. It used to be simple, but there seems to be so many different options now

1. website "likes"
2. the big box where they show the user how many of their friends like it
3. facebook connect

What are the different options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple expose: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web

Here is the full API documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Answer (score 0):

[Document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) provides links for Facebook Social Plugins such as (Like Button, Send button, Comments, Like Box.etc.) and how to integrate into your site with just line of HTML code.